# How to check whether json data array returns a value or not

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to check if an object of an array contains empty data in jquery but it doesn't seemed to work.

It returns the array values if the value passed exist in the database but if the value passed isn't correct it doesn't return any error.

Here is what I have tried so far:

PHP code

```
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $json = array();
  $id =  trim($_POST['name']);
  $query = "SELECT regiNo, firstName, middleName, lastName FROM student WHERE regiNo = ?";
  $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $statement->bind_param('s', $id);
  $statement->execute();
  $statement->bind_result($rno, $fname, $mname, $lname);
  while ($statement->fetch()){
     $user=array('rno'=>$rno,'fname'=>$fname,'mname'=>$mname,'lname'=>$lname);
      array_push($json,$user);
  }
  echo json_encode($json, true);

   }
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".Student_reg_code").blur(function () {
    var id = $(".Student_reg_code").val();
    var data = 'name=' + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //for each value in the json response
                    $(".Student_reg_code").val(data[i].id);
                    $(".regno").val(data[i].rno);
                    $(".lname").val(data[i].lname);
                    $(".mname").val(data[i].mname);
                    $(".fname").val(data[i].fname);
                } // for

            } // if
            else {
              alert('Empty value return for that'+ id);
            }

        } // success
    }); // ajax
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is always true so long as you’re returning something, even an empty array, from the request. If you want to check if the return value isn’t an empty array do `if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length)`

Comment: @Cue, Thanks for the help. Working!!

Comment: Cool. I’ll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `json_encode` is always returning a value; the `data` parameter will always be truthy. You can further test the returned data with the following expression:

```
if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length) {
  ...
}
```

[`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) will determine if `data` truly is an array and `data.length` will be your truthy/falsy to determine if it's empty or not.

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that translates to true when
>   evaluated in a `Boolean` context. All values are truthy unless they are
>   defined as falsy (i.e., except for `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and
>   `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

Another way for testing out whether an array is empty or not is this:

```
if(Array.isArray(data) && typeof data[0] !== 'undefined') {
   console.log("We got an array");
}
```

What's the advantage of this over using the length property? Well if you had a very large array the length would have to iterate the entire array, whereas this doesn't.